# how to nest a model binding in view with SAPUI5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

Data Model:

```
[{
    "id": 51,
    "name": "BuildingA",
    "floors": [{
        "id": 101,
        "name": "UG"
    }, {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "EG"
    }, {
        "id": 103,
        "name": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 104,
        "name": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 105,
        "name": "3"
    }, {
        "id": 106,
        "name": "4"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 52,
    "name": "BuildingB",
    "floors": []
}]
```

Data Binding in controller:

```
this.getView().setModel(oResponseModel, "buildingNavigation");
```

Data Binding in view:

```
<tnt:NavigationList items="{path: 'buildingNavigation>/'}">
    <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{buildingNavigation>name}" icon="sap-icon://building" expanded="true" items="{path: 'buildingNavigation>floors', templateShareable:true}">
        <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{name}">
        </tnt:NavigationListItem>
    </tnt:NavigationListItem>
</tnt:NavigationList>
```

I am working with the NavigationList from [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.tnt.sample.NavigationList/preview)

Essentially, the binding seems to work since the first level gets filled with the building names (e.g. BuildingA, BuildingB). The second level seems to work in a way that it retrieves the right amount of items. (e.g. Building A, has 6x sub levels but I am unable to receive the attribute name from the floors array. It just shows 6 empty entries in the navigation.

I tried different combinations:
e.g. `/buildingNavigation>floors>name`

All relevant information is contained and received in the model. I just don't seem to find the format to access it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner most `NavigationListItem` will too have model's alias for binding.

Your code would be:

```
<tnt:NavigationList items="{path: 'buildingNavigation>/'}">
    <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{buildingNavigation>name}" icon="sap-icon://building" expanded="true" items="{path: 'buildingNavigation>floors', templateShareable:true}">
        <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{buildingNavigation>name}">
        </tnt:NavigationListItem>
    </tnt:NavigationListItem>
</tnt:NavigationList>
```